# How is an aggregate root different from an composite?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

If an aggregate root is meant to hold references to entites that are part of the aggregate, and you are not allowed to reference these entities from other aggregate roots, then how does an aggregate root (aggregation) differ from composition which for me does exactly the same?

Comment: But why do you care the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The word "Aggregate" in DDD is not derived from the general OO concept of Aggregation.

DDD Aggregate roots are indeed closer to composites if there's a parallel to be made, but they're also much more than that.